# ACF Post Object within diffrent custom post type and wp_reset_postdata

Tags: wordpress, loops, advanced-custom-fields

I am running a loop using a custom post type named WHITEBOARD - within whiteboard I have a post object field of ***project_select*** - this references a different custom post type named PROJECTS. In my code for ***job_#*** I actually want that coming from the PROJECTS post type - it returns nothing at the moment, because it is looping in the whiteboard post type.

I tried using the default ACF post object code to pull this data, but because it also uses wp_reset_postdata - the rest of the field fail to display.

How can I get the job_# field to display from a different post type (projects)?

Code:

```
<?php $args = array('post_type' => 'whiteboard', 'author' =>  $current_user->ID, 'orderby' =>  'post_date', 'order' =>  'ASC', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ); $myposts = get_posts( $args ); foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <tr class="wb-content">
    <td><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></td>
    <td><?php the_field('job_#'); ?></td>
    <td><?php the_field('site_meeting'); ?></td>
    <td><?php the_field('client_meeting'); ?></td>
    <td><?php the_field('request_for_quote'); ?></td>
    <td><?php the_field('authority_to_proceed'); ?></td>
    <td><?php the_field('final_quote_acceptance'); ?></td>
    <td><?php the_field('draft_contracts'); ?></td>
    <td><?php the_field('final_contracts'); ?></td>
    <td><?php the_field('client_meeting_contracts'); ?></td>
    <td><?php the_field('development_approval'); ?></td>
    <td><?php the_field('building_permit'); ?></td>
    <td><?php the_field('colour_selection_docs'); ?></td>
    <td><?php the_field('client_meeting_colour'); ?></td>
    <td><?php the_field('estimate_vos'); ?></td>
    <td><?php the_field('amend_docs'); ?></td>
    <td><?php the_field('colour_selection_&_construction_certificate'); ?></td>
    <td><?php the_field('schedule_project'); ?></td>
    <td><?php the_field('purchase_orders'); ?></td>
    <td><?php the_field('matrix_&_plan_printing'); ?></td>
    <td><?php the_field('client_meeting_super'); ?></td>
    <td><?php the_field('schedule_confirmed'); ?></td>
    <td><?php the_field('site_start'); ?></td>
    <td><?php the_field('est_&_supervision_schedule'); ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code before show job_# and use $metas to display it as $metas will store all meta values of job_#.

```
global $wpdb;

$metas = $wpdb->get_results( 
  $wpdb->prepare("SELECT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta where meta_key = %s", 'job_#')
 );
```

Comment: Thankyou - so how do I show the job_#? I get:Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [meta_value] => 
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [meta_value] => 123gghhhh
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [meta_value] => 
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [meta_value] => 1111
        )

Comment: It will display all job_# value in your all projects now you have to get specific value for example if you want to get value '1111' then just echo $metas[3]->meta_value.

Comment: OK, but that just shows me the same number everytime? Each project has a different job #

Comment: then you have to get particular project for that particular whiteboard then after getting it get id of that project than use get_post_meta('project-post-id','job_#',true);